# Identifier Expected c# for unknown reason

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

Trying to make a simple app which will ask a few questions.
But for some reason, my AskQuestion function doesn't work.
I plan on adding an easily swap able database later which is why I'm trying to take a slightly more modular approach and as I am a beginner I am unsure what I did wrong. The only errors are in line 21 for the AskQuestion class.

Errors are:

> CS1001 Identifier Expected
>
> CS1514 { expected
>
> CS1513 } expected

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Quiz
{
    class Program
    {
        // Question Base
        class Question
        {
            public String question = "Empty Question";
            public String correctanswer = "Empty Answer";
            public String givenanswer = "Empty Answer";
            public String response = "Empty Response.";
            public bool cleared = false;
        }
        // Ask Base
        class void AskQuestion(Question Q)
        {
            while (Q.cleared == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Q.question);
                Q.givenanswer = Console.ReadLine();
                Q.givenanswer.ToLower();
                if (Q.givenanswer == Q.correctanswer)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Q.response);
                    Q.cleared = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong. Try again.");
                }
            }

        }

        // Main Function
        void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string Name;
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome challenger! You're going to have a good time.");
            Console.WriteLine("Make sure you use proper grammar. Or you may be stuck for no reason.");
            Console.WriteLine("What is your name challenger?");
            Name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome {0} to the challenge. I wish you best of luck. You will need it.",Name);
            Question Q1 = new Question();
            Q1.question = "What is the color of the sun?";
            Q1.correctanswer = "White";
            Q1.response = "Correct. Despite the fact it appears Yellow on earth, if you observe the sun from space, you would see it's true color. White.";
            AskQuestion(Q1);
            Q1.cleared = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Nice little warmup. But, lets get a bit serious.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Q.givenanswer.ToLower();` doesn't make the answer lowercase - it returns a new lowercase string which you needs to assign to a variable, or `Q.givenanswer = Q.givenanswer.ToLower();`

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
class void AskQuestion(Question Q)
```

to

```
void AskQuestion(Question Q)
```

This should be a method. The keyword `class` tells the compiler you want to create a inner class inside the out class `Program`

Comment: Solved it. Then why did class question work? But this one didn't?
Forgive me if it's obvious.

Comment: Because the content and declaration of `Question` makes sense as a class. By contrast, `AskQuestion` declares a return type (`void`), parameters (`Question Q`), and contains statements (like the `while` loop), which the compiler does not expect when defining a class.

Comment: @Angle, you want to learn a bit about the C# language syntax. If you write the `class` keyword, the compiler obviously expects that it is followed by a syntactically correct class declaration. A method declaration is obviously not the same syntactical structure as a class declaration, thus beginning a method declaration with the keyward `class` makes the compiler throw a hissy fit, and justifiedly so ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`Q.givenanswer.ToLower();` doesn't make `Q.givenanswer` lowercase - it returns a new lowercase string which you need to assign to a variable, or just `Q.givenanswer = Q.givenanswer.ToLower();